# Count cols, rows in table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this: [image]

How I can calculate lines (level1 + level2 ... level5) and rows (level1 + next line level1...) for total row in end of the table?

For total rows I use this:

```
function totalRow()
{
    var total = 0;
    $('#test').each(function(){
        $('.input-md').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
    $('#totalall').val(total);
}
```

Comment: As I see your code can handle everything what's questioned. Are you going to need the colum's total as well? It1s not clear from the original question.

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing... a line is a row. I guess you meant columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

html `id`s must be unique in the document. Classes may be duplicated.

`$('#test').each(function(){` doesn't make sense, because there can only be one id #test in the document. It is not looping across your rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that you forgot to select `#primary`.
You may write instead :

```
$('#test,#primary').each(function(){
    $('.input-md').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

But if you use the class `input-md` only in this table, then you can simplify it by writing :

```
$('.input-md').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. For count rows :

```
function totalRow()
{
    var total = 0;
    $('table .count-row td .cols, .total-row').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('disabled')) {
            $(this).val(total);
            total = 0;
        } else {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For count columns:

```
function totalColumns()
{
    var id = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
    var totalCol = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<=5; i++) {
        $('.column-' + id[i]).each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                totalCol += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
            $('#count-' + id[i]).text(totalCol);
        });
        totalCol = 0;
    }
}
```